# Searching for module filtering to Core compatibility 8.x, turned out it is only for 7.x

Tags: 8

Searching for module "Serial field" filtering to Core compatibility 8.x, it is listed, but going into the details turned out it is only for 7.x.
How should I avoid listing in 8.x if it is not really available?
Is there anywhere information  when it will be available?
Is it possible to get a notification when it is released for 8.x?

Answer (score 0):

Select both "Core compatibility: 8.x" and "Stability: Has a supported stable release".

The combination will filter out modules like Serial Field, which has a stable version for D7 but only a -dev version for D8.

Unfortunately, this will also hide modules with only pre-releases (even -rc) for D8, some of which are in fact quite stable in practice.

There is no way to determine how far along a "non-stable" module is without actually going to the project page and looking at the releases/issue queue. There will usually be a message like this (this is the one for Serial):

> This module has a pre-release version for Drupal 8. To find out more, follow this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2767507) or download below.

You can subscribe to these issues to get email updates when someone comments on it, and thus get alerted about development progress.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, yes it is a good hint to subscribe to the issue to get any updates, however the perfect solution would be the possibility to get alert only if the module is ready to use "stable". It would be especially important in case of 7.x -> 8.x  module upgrades, since the e-mail traffic from Drupal could be decreased.